# Objective-C dot syntax or property value?

Tags: objective-c

I keep reading that dot syntax is possible but I keep getting errors that the struct does not contain members I am referencing. Perhaps its not the dot syntax so I have included details of what I am doing in hopes of a solution:

```
//  MobRec.h - used as the objects in the MobInfo array
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MobRec : NSObject {
@public NSString *mName;        
     @public int mSpeed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mName; 
@property (nonatomic) int mSpeed;

// MobDefs.h - array of MobRecords
@interface Mobdefs : NSObject {
@public NSMutableArray *mobInfo;
}

@property(assign) NSMutableArray *mobInfo;  // is this the right property?

-(void) initMobTable;

@end

// MobDefs.m
#import "Mobdefs.h"
#import "Mobrec.h"
@implementation Mobdefs
@synthesize mobInfo;

-(void) initMobTable 
{
    // if I use traditional method I get may not respond 
    [mobInfo objectAtIndex:0 setmName: @"doug"];

    // if I use dot syntax I get struct has no member named mName 
    mobInfo[1].MName = @"eric";
}

// main.h
MobDefs *mobdef;

// main.m 
mobdef = [[Mobdefs alloc] init];
[mobdef initMobTable];
```

although both methods should work I get erros on both. What am I doing wrong? My best thoughts have been that I am using the wrong @property but I think I have tried all. I am performing alloc in main. Ideally I would like to for this use dot syntax and cant see why its not allowing it.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of things: (**edit: original point #1 removed due to error**)

2. Although the dot syntax is supported, the array index syntax for `NSArray` is not. Thus, your call to `mobInfo[1]` will *not* be the same as `[mobInfo objectAtIndex:1];` Instead, `mobInfo` will be treated as a simple C-style array, and that call would be almost guaranteed to result in a crash.
3. You should not define variables in your header file as you do in main.h. The line `MobDefs *mobdef;` belongs somewhere in main.m.

**edit:** Here is how it should look:

> **MobRec.h**

```
@interface MobRec : NSObject {
    NSString *mName;        
    int mSpeed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mName; 
@property (nonatomic) int mSpeed;
```

> **MobRec.m**

```
@implementation MobRec
@synthesize mName;
@synthesize mSpeed;
@end
```

> **MobDefs.h**

```
@interface MobDefs : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *mobInfo;
}
@property(assign) NSMutableArray *mobInfo;
-(void) initMobTable;
@end
```

> **MobDefs.m**

```
#import "MobDefs.h"
#import "MobRec.h"

@implementation MobDefs
@synthesize mobInfo;

-(void) initMobTable 
{
    // option 1:
    [(MobRec*)[mobInfo objectAtIndex:0] setMName:@"doug"];

    // option 2:
    (MobRec*)[mobInfo objectAtIndex:0].mName = @"eric";

    // option 3:
    MobRec *mobRec = [mobInfo objectAtIndex:0];
    mobRec.mName = @"eric";
}
```

> **main.m**

```
MobDef *mobdef = [[MobDefs alloc] init];
[mobdef initMobTable];
...
[mobdef release]; // don't forget!
```

Comment: I'll tack on to this since it isn't really enough for a separate 'answer':

4. When you're defining variables in your @interface, you don't need to specify @public for each one. If you put @public before the first one, all subsequent instance variables (until you specify @protected or @private) will be public.

Comment: Good point. I removed the `@public` keywords entirely, since they are not needed at all in this case.

Comment: Regarding point 1: mobInfo is a member of MobDefs, not MobRec, so synthesizing it in MobRec doesn't make sense, nor does the sample code you've posted reflect this.

Comment: Very true. Thank you for spotting that. I have removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either cast the object returned by -objectAtIndex:, or use a method call on it:

```
[[mobInfo objectAtIndex: 0] setMName: @"doug"];
```

or

```
((Mobrec *) [mobInfo objectAtIndex: 0]).MName = @"doug";
```

Comment: I think the property access should be .mName, not .MName, given his declaration. douglasrahn, it's a very bad idea to choose a property name like `mMember.` Every language has its own convention; Obj-C don't use the leading m!

Comment: There is no convention, and the m prefix is used in several Apple examples--probably written by former PowerPlant fans.

Comment: Ah, I've seen mSomething for instance variables, but not for properties:p Could you give me the link? Thanks in advance!

Comment: usually properties have no leading character; the member variables backing them frequently do, however.

Comment: If you find an example that has such a prefix, file a bug.  It is against convention.

Answer (score 0):

> [mobInfo objectAtIndex:0 setmName: @"doug"];

There is no objectAtIndex:setmName method, so you're going to have to explain what you think this is even supposed to do.

> mobInfo[1].MName = @"eric";

Use objectAtIndex to look something up in an NSArray object.

Comment: I think he meant `[[mobInfo objectAtIndex:0] setmName: @"doug"];`. The other answers seem to have corrected that.